# VSTS Hosted Linux - valgrind failing - no new code changes

Tags: valgrind, azure-pipelines

Valgrind/Helgrind/Drd starting failing on our Hosted Linux build, but we haven't made any code changes that would cause this.  In the last 2 weeks, has something changed in the image to have affected this?  I'm wondering if a new openssl library is being used.

```
2018-07-12T18:11:34.4988353Z 52: Test command: /usr/bin/valgrind "--tool=drd" "--gen-suppressions=all" "--num-callers=100" "--error-exitcode=1" "/opt/vsts/work/1/s/edgelet/hsm-sys/azure-iot-hsm-c/build/tests/edge_openssl_enc_int/edge_openssl_enc_inut_exe"
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5003466Z 52: Test timeout computed to be: 1500
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5017957Z 52: ==14258== drd, a thread error detector
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5056894Z 52: ==14258== Copyright (C) 2006-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Bart Van Assche.
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5071537Z 52: ==14258== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5086126Z 52: ==14258== Command: /opt/vsts/work/1/s/edgelet/hsm-sys/azure-iot-hsm-c/build/tests/edge_openssl_enc_int/edge_openssl_enc_inut_exe
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5104152Z 52: ==14258== 
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5123088Z 52: vex amd64->IR: unhandled instruction bytes: 0x48 0xF 0xC7 0xF0 0x72 0x2 0xE2 0xF8
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5145584Z 52: vex amd64->IR:   REX=1 REX.W=1 REX.R=0 REX.X=0 REX.B=0
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5173070Z 52: vex amd64->IR:   VEX=0 VEX.L=0 VEX.nVVVV=0x0 ESC=0F
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5244437Z 52: vex amd64->IR:   PFX.66=0 PFX.F2=0 PFX.F3=0
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5258653Z 52: ==14258== valgrind: Unrecognised instruction at address 0x5269df5.
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5273142Z 52: ==14258==    at 0x5269DF5: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1)
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5287945Z 52: ==14258==    by 0x520C61C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1)
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5302020Z 52: ==14258==    by 0x4036A5: generate_encryption_key (edge_enc_openssl_key.c:627)
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5316466Z 52: ==14258==    by 0x407497: test_generate_encryption_key_success (edge_openssl_enc_int.c:447)
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5330031Z 52: ==14258==    by 0x4079D7: RunTests (ctest.c:109)
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5346938Z 52: ==14258==    by 0x402656: main (main.c:9)
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5360888Z 52: ==14258== Your program just tried to execute an instruction that Valgrind
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5374900Z 52: ==14258== did not recognise.  There are two possible reasons for this.
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5389744Z 52: ==14258== 1. Your program has a bug and erroneously jumped to a non-code
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5403744Z 52: ==14258==    location.  If you are running Memcheck and you just saw a
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5426078Z 52: ==14258==    warning about a bad jump, it's probably your program's fault.
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5519059Z 52: ==14258== 2. The instruction is legitimate but Valgrind doesn't handle it,
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5533448Z 52: ==14258==    i.e. it's Valgrind's fault.  If you think this is the case or
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5547845Z 52: ==14258==    you are not sure, please let us know and we'll try to fix it.
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5561557Z 52: ==14258== Either way, Valgrind will now raise a SIGILL signal which will
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5574843Z 52: ==14258== probably kill your program.
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5588131Z 52: ==14258== 
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5604536Z 52: ==14258== Process terminating with default action of signal 4 (SIGILL): dumping core
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5625892Z 52: ==14258==  Illegal opcode at address 0x5269DF5
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5640250Z 52: ==14258==    at 0x5269DF5: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1)
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5654668Z 52: ==14258==    by 0x520C61C: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1)
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5668681Z 52: ==14258==    by 0x4036A5: generate_encryption_key (edge_enc_openssl_key.c:627)
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5682074Z 52: ==14258==    by 0x407497: test_generate_encryption_key_success (edge_openssl_enc_int.c:447)
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5695783Z 52: ==14258==    by 0x4079D7: RunTests (ctest.c:109)
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5709516Z 52: ==14258==    by 0x402656: main (main.c:9)
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5722745Z 52: ==14258== 
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5736713Z 52: ==14258== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5751172Z 52: ==14258== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
2018-07-12T18:11:34.5765474Z 52/52 Test #52: edge_openssl_enc_inut_drd ...........***Exception: Illegal  0.74 sec
```

Comment: You should try a newer valgrind version, as similar problems have been solved in the newer releases.

Comment: @PatrickLu-MSFT Yes, the VSTS Hosted Linux image did in fact change. The host image was installing OpenSSL 1.1 as the default. This is different than in June, when it was pointing to OpenSSL 1.0. From internal Microsoft resources, I found a solution that worked for our build:

      apt-get remove --yes libssl-dev && \ 
      apt-get install --yes --target-release xenial-updates libssl-dev